# Add existing service reference to a new project in a new solution

Tags: c#, windows-7, service-reference

I have a VS2013 C# .net 4.0 solution and one of the C# projects (console application ) has a folder called "Service References". 
In the folder, there are two subfolders

```
One is : MyReference1, it has files of 
    configuration.svcinfo
    configuration91.svcinfo
    MyApplication1.disco (web service Discovery File)
    MyApplication2.wsdl (web service description language)
    Reference.cs (Visual C# source file)
    Reference.svcmap

Another one  is: MyReference2, it has files of 
    configuration.svcinfo
    configuration91.svcinfo
    MyApplication3.wsdl 
    MyApplication4.disco
    MyApplication4_1.xsd
    MyApplication4_2.xsd
    MyApplication4_3.xsd
    MyProject.MyReference.JobStatus.datasource (visual studio data source file)
    Reference.cs
    Reference.svcmap
```

Now, for some reasons, I have to create a new project  in a new solution (of VS2013 C# .net 4.0) with exactly same services references as the above one.

After creating a new solution and a new project (which has same property as the above one), I tried to add the above existing files in the above subfolders into my new project. 
I created a new folder called "Service References" and the subfolders with the same name as above. 
But, when I build the project, I got the errors, for example,

In Reference.svcmap:

> Error 1   Custom tool error: Failed to generate file: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002) C:\MyPATH\MyProject\serviceReference\MyReference2\Reference.svcmap

In Reference.cs

> Error 5   The type or namespace name 'ServiceModel' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\MyPATH\MyProject\serviceReference\MyReference1\Reference.cs (the file was auto-generated by a tool )

The difference between the folder "Service References" in my project and in the old project is that thee are only two subfolder names under "Service References" in the old project and no files inside the folder are shown in the project. But, in my project,  all files are shown because I added them as existing items.

When I right clicked the project and add service reference by pasting the path (where the "Service References" is located) in the "Address" part, I got error:

> There was an error downloading 'C:\MyPath\Service References'.
>
> Access to the path 'C:\djx_2014_6_3\MyPath\Service References' is denied.
>
> If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

I run the VS2013 as administrator.

How to add service references correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Don't add this folders to the project as files.

You have to right-click on project -> Add... -> Service reference and then paste path to wsdl file. Do this for each service.

Also if your both projects are in one solution, you can just add a reference to project containing this services and generated code will be shared between projects. Right click on project -> Add... -> Reference -> Solution and check project containing services.

Comment: when I added the .wsdl file path to the address box in Add service reference, and pressed "Go", and then Ok, I got error: ""unable to check out the current file, The file may be read-only or locked, or you may need to check the file out manually."

Comment: it seems that you still have `service reference` folder included in projects and visual studio block access to it. Try to close VS, remove folder from solution catalog, then open VS, remove folder from solution explorer (it will clear it in .csproj file), that again Add -> Service reference -> path to wsdl (wsdl at this moment not in the solution directory). Service code will be generated from scratch.

Comment: Do these services have an address. You can find this by right clicking the service and choose the "Configure Service Reference..." option. If you find an address here, use this to follow the steps mentioned by Anton